Gerar PDF com Python Flask
Estou Desenvolvendo um Sistema para treino e estudo, quero gerar um relatório PDF, mas não sei qual Framework usar para isso, estou usando Python FLask no Back end e HTML5 com CSS3 no front, qual biblioteca ou Framework posso usar para gerar?

De uma olhada nesta lib em Python. Da uma lida também na central de ajuda para entender melhor a finalidade do site.

Existem algumas, mas gosto da PyMuPDF

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
